# help me about salting passwords

Tags: passwords, salt, password-cracking

Eve has just discovered and decrypted the file that associates each userid
with its 32-bit random salt value, and she has also discovered and decrypted the password file, which contains the salted-and-hashed passwords for the
100 people in her building. If she has a dictionary of 500,000 words and she is
confident all 100 people have passwords from this dictionary, what is the size
of her search space for performing a dictionary attack on their passwords?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that this is a homework question, I'm going to focus more on the why than the what.  The purpose of a unique salt is that it makes values that would otherwise be the same unique.  The net result is that this forces each password in the database to be attacked independently since 'abc'password does not hash to the same thing as 'dcf'password.

This means that all values have to be tried against all inputs in the worst case.  If they are evenly distributed, then it should take an average of half of the search space each time to find a match.  In the real world, people tend to follow patterns and so it goes even faster, though a dictionary of 500,000 might not go significantly faster since that's probably pretty close to the common pool of passwords when you throw in frequent letter substitutions.

Comment: This means that Eve for each user must combine dictionary word with its salt and examine it. And for 100 users it must examine 100 * 500,000 = 50,000,000. Is it ture?

Comment: Effectively, yes.  Eve must combine each dictionary word with the salt for the record she is attacking at that time.  So for the user with salt 'abc' they have to try 'abc'word1, 'abc'word2, etc etc until they get a hash that matches.  Then for the record with hash 'def' they have to try 'def'word1, 'def'word2, etc.  This does result in a maximum of 500,000 tries for each of the 100 users or 50,000,000 tries in total.

Comment: Thank you. And if Eve does not have the salt of each users she must examines 2^32 * 100 * 500,000. Is it true?

Comment: @user34221 - if Eve did not have the salt, she would have to try every possible salt and dictionary combination, so yes, however this isn't practically going to happen very often, if ever, as the salt is also necessary for the hash to be verified and isn't considered secret information.  The security of the hash should never depend on the salt remaining secret.

Comment: I think this answer is right-ish but for the wrong reason, please see my answer (and correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @JohnWu - what do you see as the wrong reason?  Your answer meanders too much for me to figure out what you think is the problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Since 100^2 is much smaller than 2^32 we can assume each salt is unique, despite being much smaller than recommended. Unique salts prevent all multi-target attacks, beyond that the salt size is irrelevant to security.

So the maximal number of guesses is 100 * 500000 = 50 million since you need to try each dictionary value with each user. Expected number of guesses is at half that if all password candidates are equally likely and much smaller than that in practice, since a rational attacker tries the most likely candidates first.

Comment: This means that Eve for each user must combine dictionary word with its salt and examine it. And for 100 users it must examine 100 * 500,000 = 50,000,000. Is it ture?

Comment: yes. For each user you look up their salt, combine it with the password candidate and hash. You do not need to look at salts used by nobody and you can't use one hash computation to compare with the hash of different users, since the different salts lead to different hashes.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are correct, but for completeness i'd like to contrast a dictionary attack with a rainbow attack.

In a rainbow attack, the hacker creates a "rainbow table" based on the dictionary.

What is a rainbow table?  A pre-computed list of the hashes associated with common words.  With the rainbow table, a hacker can perform a "reverse lookup" starting with the hash of the word and going backwards to get the cleartext-- something that is computationally unfeasible without the rainbow table (or a series of precomputed hash chains, if you're going for the space/time tradeoff, but that is another matter).  In this case the hacker has limited the common words list to 500,000.

So if there were no salt at all, the hacker would have to hash each and every word, meaning the number of rainbow table entries (the "search space") would be 500,000.

Now add in the salt.  Salt, as you know, is just something that you append to the cleartext word before computing the hash, thus making very long words that are more or less unpredictable.  With 2^32 salt values, the rainbow table explodes in size to 2^32 x 500,000, or 2.14 x 10^15, or  2,147,483,648,000,000.  Ouch.

Fortunately there aren't really 2^32 salt values.  The hacker knows all salt values in use, and there are only 100 of them (1 for each user).  So the size of the rainbow table needed is only 100 x 500,000 = 50M entries.

Contrast this with a dictionary attack.  A dictionary attack is a form of brute force attack that limits the search field by looking for common words.  This sort of attack in this case requires *at most* 100x500,000 = 50M hashing operations.

The key words are "at most."  The dictionary attack is actually considerably faster; it is pretty unlikely you'll have to compute all 500,000 hashes before finding the right one.  In a typical case you'll only have to compute 250,000, and maybe even less if you go through your dictionary in an intelligent way (most common words first.)

In contrast, with a rainbow attack (which is a type of "reverse brute force" attack) you build the rainbow table first, and it requires all 50M hashing operations before you even look at a single user record.  It isn't known for its memory efficiency!  In fact that is its primary down side.

So for extra credit, tell your professor that the dictionary attack (given the salt and the known-500,000 list of words) on each password would be more efficient than a rainbow attack, in this specific case, assuming the salt values are each unique.

An eloquent way to state this is:

*Rainbow attack*

- 500,000 x (100-Q) hashing operations + 100 comparison operations, where Q is the number of salt values that are duplicates
- Memory requirement is (500,000 x (100-Q) x hash size) + (100 x password size)

*Dictionary attack*

- 100 x (N x (1 hashing operation and 1 comparison operation)), where 1 <= N <= 500,000
- Memory requirement is (1 x hash size) + (100 x password size)

In both cases, the "search space" is 50,000,000.  Dictionary attack is superior in terms of both space and time for expected values of Q.  Rainbow attack wins if there is no salt or salt is fixed (Q = 99), and would also probably win for high values of Q.

For serious extra credit, compute Q' (where rainbow attack beats dictionary attack when Q >= Q'), in terms of number of computations.  Surely you'd get an A+.

Comment: What the questions asks about is a dictionary attack with a known dictionary of inputs.  What you are defining as a dictionary attack is actually a rainbow table attack.  The question is simply looking to have a set of possible inputs that you must try.  This answer seems to meander and be misleading and doesn't add anything not covered in the other answers.

Comment: Explained another way, a dictionary attack is an attack that enhances the performance of brute force by selecting likely inputs based on a dictionary and trying them.  A rainbow table is when you run a number of inputs and store the outputs so that they can be compared against outputs to lookup the input.  The two are not the same.  A true brute force attack would start at a, then b, then c... z then aa then ab, etc.  There is no intelligence which is why it is called brute force.

Comment: I +1 as well as the rest of the answers. I think you did a decent job at explaining the process, just got a few terms mixed up. Nothing an small edit can't fix.

Comment: It's worth noting that I agree with David Houde that this can be fixed with some edits to correct terms and remove the incorrect parts.  I would be more than happy to change my -1 to a +1 if the issues are fixed, but as it stands now, it needs correction to stop it from being misleading.  Currently it would give someone an incorrect understanding, that's the only reason I downvoted.

Comment: I was going to delete, but you guys are so awesome I edited as suggested.  Hopefully this answer is of some value now